# how no to repeat the same code in multiple files

Tags: html

I've noticed that I'm repeating the same code in multiple files while developing a website.

The most common thing is to repeat navigation and footer, but also inline PHP script in HTML file that checks whether the user is logged in.

Since the website is small (less then 10 pages), making a change to all of this files is doable, but time consuming.

I am sure I am not the only on who noticed this.. What is the usual workflow for such scenarios? What tools should I use?

EDIT:

I am looking for plain HTML generator. Write in 1 file, use in many. JS is undesired. It makes little sense to use it, if you want to display static pages.

Comment: Functions and `include`?

Comment: no JS solution would be great for html part

Comment: JS works as well

Comment: Use the php include function.

Answer (score 0):

As said by @KevinLewis in comments, use [`include` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

**Your footer.**

```
<?php
echo "<p>Copyright &copy; 1999-" . date("Y") . " W3Schools.com</p>";
?>
```

**Your page**

```
<html>
  <body>
     <h1>Welcome to my home page!</h1>
     <p>Some text.</p>
     <p>Some more text.</p>

     <?php include 'footer.php';?>

  </body>
</html>
```

source: [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp)